# How to Post the Form values to the Controller in Mvc without Model and uSing Ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to post the from Property name and values to the Mvc web api Controller without using model Property because i need to use same Ajax call (method) for different Forms also.

Using this Ajax Method i need to Post values i am Posting values but how i need to receive those values in Controller

Example Of Posting:

```
function Add(){var model = $("#Enquiry").serialize();  
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:60533/api/Enquiry',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: model,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});}
```

Using Below Controller how can i Receive model Values without using C# (Get set Property) Model?

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(object model)
    {
        var Result = (new EnquiryDtl().Post(model));
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Why is your model of type `object`?  Surely you can be more specific than that.  Either with a custom class (any simple POCO would do) or separated properties of the individual parameter types (strings, integers, etc.).  The data that you're posting must follow *some* predictable structure, no?

Comment: in my Form more then 10 Fields are there if we are declaring data type for those parameter it's not Good. so if i got all data in Object then i can insert those values using for each.

Comment: How is using statically-typed values "not good"?  I don't think you understand how C# is designed to work...

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it...

```
var dataArray = $("#Enquiry").serializeArray(),
var model = {};
for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++)
    model[dataArray[i].name] = dataArray[i].value;
var url = 'http://localhost:60533/api/Enquiry';
$.ajax({
    url: url, type: "POST", dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(model), contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        ....
    }
});
```

and in the controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Dictionary<string, string> fields)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've undoubtedly discovered, `object` doesn't have a lot of useful properties on it.  This is where using a model really comes in handy.  For example, let's say you're posting an integer called `ID` and a string called `Name`, then this simple object would be populated accordingly:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And you'd use it in your method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyModel model)
{
    // here you can access model.ID and model.Name
}
```

If you *really* don't want to use a model, you can include the values directly in the method signature:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id, string name)
{
    // here you can access id and name
}
```

Of course, using a model brings a lot more advantages.  Specifically, you can add business logic to the model (since business logic belongs on the models and not on the controllers).  Additional benefits include being able to modify the structure without having to modify all consuming code.  (For example, if you have multiple methods which accept this structure then you'd have to change all of them to add a new field.  With a model, you'd only have to change that one model.)

Comment: actual,what i am Trying to do is i need to get the key pair values of the Form, i need to apply the same Ajax script file for more then  two domains in that my Property names will change so i can't stick to the exact names that is the Problem, so in each domain the property names will differ.  and also this script i need to write for main domain so any one fill the Contact Form it will it to the main Domain there i need to get the Form values..

Comment: actual what your trying to say is correct only but the Problem is If i am using Model i need to use the Common model for all the domain,if i am 15 sub domain i can't initialize 15 model so if we are passing all the values in the object then we can insert those values.

Comment: @Raj: Why can't the different applications use the same model?  If they're all .NET projects then they can all reference a single common library.  If they're not all .NET then no solution would commonly work across all of them.

Comment: in different application the property names will vary suppose in domain 1 it as 10 property in domain 2 15 property so like this Property will increase and there names will also changes. if i am doing wih object then i will receive values like (Name:"Raj",Age:"20") so we can get the Key pair value of this Object and also if our Property names is increased then that also automatically that will be Present in the Object but in case of model we have go and intialze the Property Names.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the Solution To send the Key Pair values to the Mvc Controller using Ajax and web Api.

Without using C# Model get set property

My Script:

```
function Enquiry() {
var dataArray = $("#formMember").serializeArray(),
model = {};
for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
   var Name = "["+i+"]"+""+"."+"Key";
   var Value = "[" + i + "]" + "" + "." + "Value" 
   model[Name] = dataArray[i].name;
   model[Value] = dataArray[i].value;
}
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:60533/api/Enquiry',
    type: 'POST',
    data: model,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});}
```

C# Code

I am reciving Those values Instead of Object I am Using Dictionary

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        var Result = (new EnquiryDtl().Post(dictionary));
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```